# How to call methods with same name but in different, unrelated classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing c# script in Unity

```
public class something1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Dosomething(){

    }
}

public class something2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Dosomething(){

    }
}

public class callingDoSometing
{
    public void callALLDosomething(){
        something1 s1 = new something1();
        something2 s2 = new something2();
        something3 s3 = new something3();
        something4 s4 = new something4();
        .
        .
        .
        s1.Dosomething();
        s2.Dosomething();
        s3.Dosomething();
        s4.Dosomething();
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

I need to call methods with same names (here `Dosomething()`) from different classes.
Actually I need something like multiple inheritance in other OOP languages and I don't want to create additional languages.

Comment: Make a common interface that all your classes implement?

Comment: `someting1 s4 = new something4();` You have a class cast exception here. Cannot cast `something4` to `something1`

Comment: You shouldn't use `new` to instantiate `MonoBehaviours`. You should use `AddComponent` instead.

Comment: Do you control the definitions of classes `Something1` and `Something2`? That is, can you change their source code and recompile them, or are they given to you and you cannot change them?

Comment: Since you where looking for https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+multiple+inheritance+alternatives why did not you try regular "use interfaces" suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is accomplished with interfaces.

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
    void Dosomething();
}
public class something1 : MonoBehaviour, IDoSomething
{
    public void Dosomething() { }
}
public class something2 : MonoBehaviour, IDoSomething
{
    public void Dosomething() { }
}
```

If you are trying to dynamically discover these classes, you would do something like this:

```
public class CallingDoSomething
{
    private Type[] Get_IDoSomethingTypes()
    {
        var allTypes = typeof(CallingDoSomething).Assembly.GetTypes();
        var searchFor = typeof(IDoSomething);

        return allTypes.Where(x => searchFor.IsAssignableFrom(x))
                       .Where(x => x.IsClass)
                       .ToArray();
    }
    public void CallAllSomethings()
    {
        var types = Get_IDoSomethingTypes();
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var instance = (IDoSomething)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            instance.Dosomething();
        }
    }
}
```

If you already have a collection these classes instantiated, you would just always treat them like they are IDoSomething objects:

```
public class CallingDoSomething
{
    private List<IDoSomething> m_somethingDoers = new List<IDoSomething>();
    public void OtherCodeThatPopulatedSomethingDoers()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void CallAllSomethings()
    {
        foreach (var s in m_somethingDoers)
            s.Dosomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is the closest understending question and answering on it (Yes i cant form my thoughts into question clearly). But how to "foreach" for instances with exact type?

Answer (score 3):

Typically the way you'd do this in C# is to declare an interface; you can implement arbitrarily many interfaces, but only extend one base type.

```
interface IDoSomething
{
  void DoSomething();
}
public class Thing1 : SomeBaseClass, IDoSomething
{
    public void DoSomething(){ }
}
public class Thing2 : SomeBaseClass, IDoSomething
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}
```

And now you can use `IDoSomething` as a type:

```
IDoSomething i1 = new Thing1();
IDoSomething i2 = new Thing2();
i1.DoSomething();
i2.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Note that in Unity interfaces can be retrieved as components using gameObject.GetComponent<IDoSomething>() as well, but only abstract classes can be placed into the inspector. If there is a need for these monobehaviours to be dragged and dropped into inspector, a similar approach with abstract classes can be used.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But I have another one. Is there a way to call all DoSomething() in any order if I don't know classes or objects have it?

Comment: @linesra: Again, it sounds a lot like you're asking XY questions here. What's the problem you actually have?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you want to do this to two `MonoBehaviours` that don't otherwise have a common parent might indicate some questionable engineering, but it is possible to do exactly this using [`GameObject.SendMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html).

```
public class something1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Dosomething(){

    }
}

public class something2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Dosomething(){

    }
}

public class callingDoSometing
{
    public void callALLDosomething(){
        GameObject g1 = new GameObject();
        g1.AddComponent<something1>();

        GameObject g2 = new GameObject();
        g2.AddComponent<something1>();

        GameObject g3 = new GameObject();
        g3.AddComponent<something2>();

        GameObject g4 = new GameObject();
        g4.AddComponent<something2>();


        ...

        g1.SendMessage("Dosomething"); 
        g2.SendMessage("Dosomething"); 
        g3.SendMessage("Dosomething"); 
        g4.SendMessage("Dosomething"); 
    }
}
```

Just be aware that doing this will call `Dosomething` on every MonoBehaviour on that gameobject.

If you want to be specific about which `MonoBehaviour` to call on and/or have the references to the `MonoBehaviour`s specifically, you can use [`MonoBehaviour.Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html):

```
public class something1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Dosomething(){

    }
}

public class something2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Dosomething(){

    }
}

public class callingDoSometing
{
    public void callALLDosomething(){
        GameObject g1 = new GameObject();
        MonoBehaviour m1 = g1.AddComponent<something1>();

        GameObject g2 = new GameObject();
        MonoBehaviour m2 = g2.AddComponent<something1>();

        GameObject g3 = new GameObject();
        MonoBehaviour m3 = g3.AddComponent<something2>();

        GameObject g4 = new GameObject();
        MonoBehaviour m4 = g4.AddComponent<something2>();


        ...

        m1.Invoke("Dosomething",0f);
        m2.Invoke("Dosomething",0f);
        m3.Invoke("Dosomething",0f);
        m4.Invoke("Dosomething",0f);
    }
}
```